# Visual Studio serial communications

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serial-port, label

[IMAGEEEEEEE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGesw.png) I'm using Visual Studio c# forms and I can't get the label to display everything the serial port reads, is there an easy way to fix this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            serialPort1.Open();
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: serialPort1.ReadLine() will only get you the first line of data received by the Port, if you want to show all data, you need to read each line into a string variable and then set your label text property to that. Check out my answer below.

Comment: Just google the exception you get, lots and lots of hits.

Comment: Ryan, How would I go about doing that? I'm fairly new to Visual Studio

Comment: @AlexanderSacco Please see my answer below. Nevermind, actually try other person's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var dataLength = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
    var data = new byte[dataLength];
    var nbrDataRead = serialPort1.Read(data, 0, dataLength);

    if (nbrDataRead == 0)
        return;

    Label1.Text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

Comment: Okay, I got it to work but how do you only leave the last line that was displayed on the label @scor4er

Comment: I'm not quite got what you mean. Do you want to put a data from the serial port to the new label's line every time you receive it?

Comment: Yeah, whenever data is received from the serial port it should overwrite the previous data @scor4er

Comment: Anyone have an answer to this?

Comment: Still don't understand how is it different comaping with what you have now? The label text currently is overwritten every time you receive a data.

Comment: look at the top, I have an image in the form of a link that shows the issue im having @scor4er

Comment: Hm, you could try to set: serialPort1.NewLine = ""; before you open your port.